# WiX Toolset - building lots of unique versions

Tags: wix, windows-installer

We need to embed a license file in the installation that is unique for every customer. We used to do this by patching the exe-installer on the webserver during download, but cloud-based anti-virus and Windows 8 is causing us problems. We are looking at WiX toolset instead.

Signing installers on the webserver does not look easy, so we have tried to limit the number of unique installers. We still need to generate 500 unique installers that only differ on one small file.

The `light.exe` takes fairly long to run. Is there a quicker way to just change one file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't help wonder if Windows 8 wouldn't still make your life hell.  If you build and sign an MSI for each customer but with slightly different contents they will all have different hashes and Microsoft's security features will probably warn that it's not safe because *this* MSI isn't downloaded often.

This `feature` kills me.  Ihave an open source project on CodePlex that is digitally signed and yet Windows 8 still acts all defensive with statements along the lines of we've protected you from dangerous software.  This software isn't downloaded very often.... jeesh.

Perhaps you can implement this in some other way.  Maybe one MSI with all the licenses and the user types in a license key that dynamically selects the correct license?  That way there is only 1 MSI.

Comment: Our standard version will all use the same MSI. The problem is the versions for schools and students. To avoid support issues we really want the installer to have no options. We haven't figured out any other option than to create unique installers to include the watermark.

Comment: After a few days of thinking we have decided to follow your suggestion and try with only one MSI. Thank you for pushing us to try!